# Iterate Items in Their Specific Groups in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, iteration

In my Django template I want to be able to iterate through groups and items, but I want to iterate the items underneath their group. So far I have them iterating like this but it does not show which groups the items are a part of. How would I iterate the template to get this inclusion?

Views:

```
def manage(request):
    group_list = Group.objects.order_by('name').filter(user=request.user)
    item_list = Item.objects.order_by('name').filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'manage.html', {'group_list': group_list, 'item_list': item_list})
```

Template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% for group in group_list %}
    {{ group.name }}<br />
{% endfor %}

{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ item.name }}<br />
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

UPDATE

Models (Sorry forgot to include this):

```
class Group(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: What are the `Group` and `Item` objects?

Comment: How are groups and items affiliated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a fk from item to group

```
class Item(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

views:

```
def manage(request):
    group_list = Group.objects.order_by('name').filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'manage.html', {'group_list': group_list})
```

template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% for group in group_list %}
    {{ group.name }}<br />

    <p>Item for this group</p>
    {% for item in group.item_set.all %}
        {{item.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 4):

Your approach does unneccessary additional database hits. For performance reasons you should select just the items with related groups like this:

```
def manage(request):
  item_list = Item.objects.order_by(
                'group__name', 'name').filter(
                user=request.user).select_related('group')
  return render(request, 'manage.html', {'item_list': item_list})
```

The template looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for item in item_list %}
  {% ifchanged item.group.name %}
    {{ item.group.name }}<br />
  {% endifchanged %}
  {{ item.name }}<br />
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

That way you only have ONE database hit regardless of how many groups there are.